# Embed custom Spotify playlist on Facebook app

Tags: facebook, spotify

I'm looking for some more information on how to embed a custom Spotify playlist into a Facebook app. If ads must be served every few songs, I wanted to see if there was a way (paid) to serve up my own ads. I'm also curious how the player will work on mobile.

If anyone out there knows of any good resources or could point me in the direction of someone who can help, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation of the spotify api and see if it's possible to do that? https://developer.spotify.com/

Comment: I have, but as far as I know you will need access to the Spotify app to actually play the songs. I'm looking for a self-contained solution, where the music can play in a standalone player on the app, like your average mp3 player. Also, I know Spotify plays ads every few songs. I wanted to see if there was a way around this or the ability to customize the ads.

Comment: I know that's possible to embed a player with a playlist made by you, but you can't manage/change the ads they play, the only thing you can do is remove them by going premium

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) setting its Spotify URI to your playlist's URI.

You don't have control of the ads, since the Play Button launches the Spotify Player and that is the one that shows or not ads depending on the user account.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So as far as you know, there is no way to have a self-contained player embedded in a website or web app without the need to launch and log into Spotify?

Comment: Also, as a paid advertiser, could you serve up only your ads during the length of a campaign?